# How to use multiple urls with PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL

Tags: python, pip

I want to configure my pip using environmental variables. I already have two pip index urls. So I'm already using PIP_INDEX_URL and PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL variables.

```
PIP_INDEX_URL="https://example.com"
PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="https://example2.com"
```

But I want to add one more index url. I don't know how

I tried to add it with `;`

```
PIP_INDEX_URL="https://example.com"
PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="https://example2.com;https://example3.com"
```

But it didn't seem to work

Comment: If I were you I would try with an empty space between 2 URLs. See [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Pip* expects an empty space ( ) to separate the values in environment variables. In this case, for example:

```
PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="https://example2.com https://example3.com"
```

See [*pip*'s documentation section "*Environment variables*"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables).